# Shiny app is only half of browser window

Tags: r, shiny

I've recently started learning Shiny and am developing my first practice app. For some reason, my app doesn't take up the entire browser window but is cutoff about half way. The page can still scroll down to see the rest of the output but there is a high fold for some reason. Below is my code:

```
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)

thesis <- read.csv("thesis.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Annual Prices by City"),

  # Sidebar with choice selected
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("city","City",as.character(thesis$city)),
      tableOutput("table")
    ),

    # Show a time series line plot
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("cityheader"),
      plotOutput("plot", width="100%")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    thesis %>%
      select(city, year, price) %>%
      filter(city == input$city)

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df(), aes(x=year, y=price)) + 
      labs(title=input$city, x="Year", y="Annual Avg Price") + 
      geom_line(col="blue") 

  }, height=400, width = 700)

  output$table <- renderTable({
    df()

  })

  output$cityheader <- renderText({
    input$city
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Here is a screenshot of the white space:

[Screenshot of the Shiny App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdyKD.png)

UPDATE:

Here is what it looks like from within the viewer's pane in Rstudio:

[Rstudio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giuow.png)

Thanks.

Comment: How does it look within Rstudio?

Comment: I updated with an Rstudio screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, try

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = 1080))
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!