# Shiny (R) - new output limited to a small part of the window after login

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny App which start only after a log-in session. I have several possibilities, according to the login different R files are picked up by the program. Everything is working, except that the output that I obtain is limited to a part of the window after the login and a "TRUE" is printed under that.

Here the code:

```
Logged = FALSE; 
my_username <- c("test01", "test02", "test03", "test04", "test05", "test06", "test07", "test08")
my_password <- c("test01", "test02", "test03", "test04", "test05", "test06", "test07", "test08")
# Define UI for data upload app
ui1 <- function() {
tagList(
div(
  id = "login",
  wellPanel(
    textInput("userName", "Username"),
    passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
    br(),
    actionButton("Login", "Log in")
  )
),
tags$style(
  type = "text/css",
  "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}"
)
)
}
ui2 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui2_uniq.R", local =T)
}
ui3 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui3_uniq.R", local =T)
}
ui4 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui4_uniq.R", local =T)
}
ui5 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui5_uniq.R", local =T)
  }
ui6 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui6_uniq.R", local =T)
    }
ui7 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui7_uniq.R", local =T)
    }
ui8 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui8_uniq.R", local =T)
    }
ui9 <- function() { source ("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui9_uniq.R", local =T)
    }
ui =   (htmlOutput("page"))
# Define server logic to read selected file
server <- function(input, output) {
USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)
observe({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
    if (input$Login > 0) {
      Username <- isolate(input$userName)
      Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
      Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
      Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
      if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
        if (Id.username == Id.password) {
          USER$Logged <- TRUE
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
 })
observe({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  output$page <- renderUI({
    div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
  })
}
if (USER$Logged == TRUE)
{ output$page<- renderUI({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  do.call(bootstrapPage, c("", ui1()))
} else
{
if (input$Login > 0) {
  if (input$userName == "test01") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui2())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName == "test02") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui3())
  }
  else
    if (input$userName== "test03") {
      do.call(bootstrapPage, ui4())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName == "test04") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui5())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName == "test05") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui6())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName == "test06") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui7())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName == "test07") {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui8())
  }
  else
  if (input$userName != "test02" & input$userName!= "test03" & input$userName != "test04" & input$userName != "test05" & input$userName!= "test06" & input$userName != "test07" ) {
    do.call(bootstrapPage, ui9())
  }
    }
    }

  })
  }
  })
}
# Create Shiny app
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Any idea how to solve the problem, i.e. how to have an output through all the window and without the "TRUE" printed?

---

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136774/shiny-app-is-only-half-of-browser-window?rq=1) which seemed to answer to my question but it does not work in my case. I think that the problem is try to understand where the "TRUE" comes from. Any suggestion?

---

Following the comment, I try to add one of the codes that are called by source (it's partial)

```
load("~/data_for_analysis.Rda")
# Define UI for data upload app
ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("TITOLO",
tabPanel("Per tipologia",
mainPanel(
# Button
  downloadButton("dowoutput1", "Download"),
  tableOutput("output1")
)
),
tabPanel("Plot",
sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "scelta", label = "Tipologia",
            choices = c("Ultimi 10 anni", "Ultimi 4 anni", "Evoluzione fascia A", "Evoluzione articoli index", "Evoluzione riviste valutate", "Evoluzione riviste scientifiche", "Evoluzione riviste non scientifiche", "Evoluzione libri", "Evoluzione capitoli", "Evoluzione capitoli index", "Evoluzione atti", "Evoluzione atti index" ) )),
mainPanel(plotOutput("hist"))
  ),
  tabPanel("Per numero di autori",
  mainPanel(  # Button
      downloadButton("dowoutput2", "Download"),
  tableOutput("output2"))
    ),
    tabPanel("Per numero di autori stesso dipartimento",
    mainPanel(# Button
        downloadButton("dowoutput3", "Download"),
    tableOutput("output3"))
      ),
      tabPanel("Punteggio",
      mainPanel(# Button
          downloadButton("dowoutput4", "Download"),
      tableOutput("output7"))
        )
  ))


# Define server logic to read selected file
server <- function(input, output) {

database_analysis <- reactive({
      database_a <- subset(database_merged, database_merged$dipartimento == "A")

      database_a
})

RE1 <- reactive({


  database_a <- database_analysis()
  database_department <- database_a

  # Generate number of products
  database_department$n_products <- rep(1)

  ...

   # Save the dataset
 save(database_1,file="Output_R/Final/depart_1.Rda")

 return(database_1)

 })

output$output1 <- renderTable({
RE1()
}, striped=TRUE, width= "10cm", align ="c")

output$dowoutput1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
      paste("tipologia-",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
      write.csv(RE1() ,file,row.names=F)
    }
  )
...
output$output7 <- renderTable({
                          RE4()
                          })

        output$dowoutput4 <- downloadHandler(
                          filename = function() {
                          paste("punteggio-",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
                          },
                          content = function(file) {
                          write.csv(RE4() ,file,row.names=F)
                          }
                          )

}

# Create Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing your `source` statements with things like  `source("/Users/nbrugali/Dropbox/Ui2_uniq.R", local =T)$value`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be the solution. If I do it, the output is an error message "cannot coerce type "closure" to vector of type "character"

Comment: I cannot find any solution to the problem.. any suggestion? this is really annoying ... could it be related to the use of bootstrapPage after the do.call?

Comment: Can you post the files that you source? When a user is logged in, you run a `uiX()` function which `source`s a file. When you load a file with source, everything in that file is run as if you typed it into the console. Most likely you have something in that file that is returning or printing `TRUE` before it gets to whatever actually generates the page. You should check those files and see if you can edit them down to just function declarations (which you call in the `uiX()` function).

Comment: If I run the single file without calling them from the "general login file" they work perfectly in all the window without any TRUE. The files are really long, I don't think it is possible to copy them here...