# R shiny app only half page in browser is showing

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have checked the post [Shiny app is only half of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136774/shiny-app-is-only-half-of-browser-window) and I've tried JJ1603's suggestion. 
I added

```
options = list(height = 1080)
```

but my map is still showing half page in browser.

I've also tried

```
library("htmlwidgets")

window_height <- JS('window.innerHeight')
window_width <- JS('window.innerWidth')

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = window_height, width = window_width))
```

but it's still not working.

## my code

```
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(     
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {     
  data <- read.csv("dat.csv")    
  })


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data) %>%           
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%          
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~ long, 
                       lat= ~ lat, 
                       color = "#00d4ff", 
                       radius = factor(data$freq),
                       label = lapply(labs, HTML),
                       clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
      )
  })
}
# Run the application 
# shinyApp(ui, server)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = window_height, width = window_width))
```

Comment: Set the width for leafletOutput. 
leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100"). Try it.

Comment: oh it made the map width really small :/ 
but your suggestion led me straight to an answer. I used height instead of weight: leafletOutput("mymap", height = "95vh")
thanks a lot Jim =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked :

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  leafletOutput("mymap", height = "95vh")
)
```

Thanks to Jim Todd =)

Comment: nice one! Thank you!!